# Add a css class to random items in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs-scope

I"m going to start by saying i know almost nothing about Angular, but i've been asked to trouble shoot this.

The final output is an isotope based display, and after the first item, the rest of the items need to been one or two sizes. The large size class (largeIsR) would be randomly added.

Here's the code snippet

```
ng-class='{largeIs:$first, adTile: TripIdea.AdTile == true, **largeIsR:$index == randomNum** && TripIdea.AdTile == false && !$first}'
```

The portion in bold is where the randomportion is happening. The feedback i've been given is, it's not random enough. So we need more of the large size to be displayed.

As we need the largeIsR classed added prior to isotope kicking in, i'm hesitant in trying it with plain javascript.

So, can someone point me towards an example i can leverage?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In angular, ng-class will append all classes where the equation is true for an object (like in the example you have). I would change `largeIsR:$index == randomNum && TripIdea.AdTile == false && !$first` into a function and place it on the scope. Find the controller for the view you are using, and add this...

```
$scope.isLargeIsR = function(){ /*Your random function that returns true or false*/}
```

Then change your html to `ng-class='{largeIs:$first, adTile: TripIdea.AdTile == true, largeIsR:isLargeIsR() && TripIdea.AdTile == false && !$first}'`